# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut') when npm i styled-components

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\react_sce\test1> npm i styled-components
```

> npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-10T09_34_26_806Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 24):

To Fix this, use specifically 5.3.10 version of styled-components

For projects using JS/JSX (JavaScript)

```
npm install styled-components@5.3.10
```

For projects using TS/TSX (TypeScript)

```
npm install styled-components@5.3.10 @types/styled-components
```

Comment: I am on MacOS, a brand new create-react-app ts project, and have the exact same issue. I need to add `--force` to make it work: `npm install styled-components@5.3.10 @types/styled-components --force`

Answer (score 0):

For this error use:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest `styled-components` version 5.

with `npm` 
`npm install styled-components@5`

with `yarn` 
`yarn add styled-components@5`